# How do you resolve error "type 'Session' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' when updating a Sqlite db with an object?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to update a sqlite database I have with the type of object that was initially sent to it when it was created. When I try to update it, I keep getting the error detailed in the question title. Why am I getting this on update and how would I address it? It created the db fine and stored the initial data fine. If I left anything out let me know! Thanks!

Where I create the new Session object and send it over to update the db

```
onTap: () {
Session session = new Session();
session.selectedQuarterStatus = quarter[index].status;
session.selectedQuarter = quarter[index].quarter;
SessionDBProvider.sessionDB.updateSession(session);
Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

This is where the db is created. Nothing crazy

```
  newSession(Session newSession) async {
    final db = await database;

    var res = await db.rawInsert('''
    INSERT INTO session (
      selected_quarter, status
    ) VALUES (?, ?)
    ''', [
      newSession.selectedQuarter,
      newSession.selectedQuarterStatus
    ]);

    return res;
  }
```

This is where I attempt to update the function with the Session object, and it errors out

```
  Future<dynamic> updateSession(session) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.update("session", session);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your Session model class has a `toMap()` method. You need to `map()` your model while updating the database. It should look like this:

```
Future<dynamic> updateSession(session) async {
  final db = await database;
  var res = await db.update("session", session.toMap());
}
```

You can read more from the [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite).